# Куда Google Drive API сохраняет файлы?

Tags: api, google-drive

Скрипт успешно отгружает файл на google drive, но занятое место на диске как было 0, так и осталось. А доступ к файлу предоставляется через share.

[image: скриншот google drive]

**Вопрос:** где тогда хранятся файлы и какой объем этого хранилища? Можно ли загружать сразу в корневую папку моего google drive аккаунта?

Вот мой Python3.6 скрипт:

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.auth import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime

import os

# Auth
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.auth_method = 'service'
gauth.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/path/to/client_secrets.json',  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Set path to backup file
backups = '/path/to/backups/'
zip_name = datetime.now().strftime("bac_%Y-%m-%d.zip")

# Create and upload file
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': zip_name})
file1.SetContentFile(backups + zip_name)
file1.Upload()

# Share access to me
file1.InsertPermission({
    'type': 'user',
    'value': 'myGoogleDriveAccountEmail@gmail.com',
    'role': 'reader'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать "куда" - узнайте "кому".

Посмотрите, кому принадлежит файл, именно то пространство он и занимает.

Не знаком с `pydrive`, но судя по всему, вы используете кредиты сервисного аккаунта (служебной учетной записи).

> Служебная учетная запись - это особый тип учетной записи, используемый приложением или экземпляром виртуальной машины, а не человеком. Приложения используют такие учетные записи для выполнения авторизованных вызовов API, авторизованных либо как сама служебная учетная запись, либо как пользователи Google Workspace или Cloud Identity посредством средств делегирования домена.

Т.о. на свой Диск вы можете загрузить файлы только при делегировании прав через домен.

#### Google Workspace

Используете ли вы Google Workspace? Тогда где-то тут нужно указать пользователя `user_email` как-то так

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    "/path/to/client_secrets.json", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
)
credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)
gauth.credentials = credentials
```

*этот код может не работать, см. документацию к pydrive*

Просто укажите настройки делегирования.

#### Обычный потребитель (например, gmail.com)

Но, скорее всего, вы не используете Google Workspace и поэтому ваша служебная учетная запись загружает файлы к себе на Диск.

В данном случае вам нужно авторизоваться от имени обычного пользователя и передать его кредиты библиотеке, чтобы код выполнялся для конкретного аккаунта. Это довольно просто https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
# Create local webserver and auto handles authentication.
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

Обратите внимание, что по дефолту код настроен на поиск файла авторизации под именем `client_secrets.json` именно в корневой папке проекта https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication